# Prevent "test/expect/etc is not defined" errors when using Jest

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, jestjs, undefined-symbol

Facebook's Jest testing framework is easy to [get started with, but the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html) overlooks an [annoying aspect](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3762#issuecomment-307597144): test statements will be highlighted as errors by any editor that tries to warn of undefined symbols, because `test`, `expect`, and all matcher methods are not defined.

[image: WebStorm highlights errors in Jest test file]

Similary, attempting to run a test file with `node` directly will fail with `ReferenceError: test is not defined`.

What `require`/`import` statement(s) need to be added for those errors to go away?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Node

<strike>If you want to run them directly through node, try to **require** `jest` and/or `jest-runtime`.</strike> Also give `@types/jest` a try as well.

**Check Edit 2 for new info about this**

**Edit**

`@types/jest` (`jest-DefinitelyTyped`) is **definitely needed** (or just one solution). If you **install it** (e.g., dev dependency), the IDE errors should go away.
I just tried it on Webstorm, and it works.

**Edit 2**

The new **Jest@20 Matchers** (e.g., `.resolves` and `.rejects`) are still not defined in `@types/jest`. You can keep track of its status on the links below:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/16645
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16803

It should be available soon, though!

Also, it doesn't seem possible to run it directly through node. Last night I tried a bunch of different things, but using jest is the way to go - **it really uses node under the hood**, so I thought it would be possible as well. **@thymikee** over your opened issue at GitHub made clear that it's not.

**Edit 3**

The new release (**20.0.1**) includes the newest Jest definitions.

### Lint

*this isn't in the scope of this specific problem, but it also helps*

Are you using something like **ESLint**? If so, you'll need `eslint-plugin-jest`

Following the steps described in this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jest, you will basically need to add it as an ESLint plugin and set jest globals in the ESLint configuration:

```
{
  "env": {
    "jest/globals": true
  }
}
```

If you plan on supporting **ES6 tests**, you'll also need `Babel` and `babel-jest` plugin with the following jest configuration:

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
}
```

Finally, for **Typescript** tests you'd need the `@types/jest` and `ts-jest` packages as well

Comment: I use WebStorm actually (ESLint on its own, extending the `google` preset, doesn't even bother to report undefined symbols - you can have `bogusfunc(foo)` in your code and it won't report it), and WebStorm underlines `expect` statements even after adding and configuring `eslint-plugin-jest`. Also, running eslint with or without the plugin says nothing about `test` or `expect` being (un)defined. Not using TypeScript, just ES6.

Comment: Try to install @types/jest either way. It worked for me on webstorm. Visual studio code also points test and expect to the typescript definitions.

Comment: Or if you really don't want it as a dev dependency, add it as a webstorm library: File - Languages - JavaScript - libraries - download - and under typescript search for jest-DefinitelyTyped

Comment: Adding that WebStorm library fixed `test`, `describe`, `expect` and the matchers, but `rejects` is still underlined as `Unresolved variable` . Adding `jest-matchers-DefinitelyTyped` didn't fix that either.

Comment: I run into that issue the other day while using Typescript, and found that those new Jest@20 Matchers are still not defined in `@types/jest`.
Going to update the answer with some links

Comment: The new @types/jest release (**20.0.1**) includes the newest Jest definitions.

Comment: Thank you so much for mentioning `eslint-plugin-jest`. Although the setup instructions related to `env` and `transform` did not work for me, the vanilla setup instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jest did.

Answer (score 44):

Adding following .eslintrc configuration is enough

```
{"env": 
  {
    "jest": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect & sweet :) (with jest 24.9.0 & eslint 6.8.0)

Comment: Or if you have `eslintConfig` defined in package.json, append this to the "env" settings also works

Answer (score 31):

I'm using VSCode and ESLint, you need to install [eslint-plugin-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jest)

Add jest info to your `.eslintrc.js`

```
{
  "plugins": ["jest"]
},
"env": {
  "jest/globals": true
}
```

Comment: simply correct with jest 28 ty